# Scrapy doesn't crawl all pages

Tags: python, scrapy

This is my working code:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class Test2Item(Item):
    title = Field()

from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class Khmer24Spider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'khmer24'
    allowed_domains = ['www.khmer24.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.khmer24.com/']
    USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.97 Safari/537.22 AlexaToolbar/alxg-3.1"
    DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'ad/.+/67-\d+\.html'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        i = Test2Item()
        i['title'] = (hxs.select(('//div[@class="innerbox"]/h1/text()')).extract()[0]).strip(' \t\n\r')
        return i
```

It can scrap only 10 or 15 records. Always random numbers! I can't manage to get all pages that has the pattern like http://www.khmer24.com/ad/any-words/67-anynumber.html

I really suspect that Scrapy finished crawling because of duplicate the request. They have suggested to use `dont_filter = True` however, I have no idea of where to put it in my code. 
I'm a newbie to Scrapy and really need help.

Comment: idk if this is related but there are many affilliate links out there that do javascript redirects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1."They have suggested to use **dont_filter = True** however, I have no idea of where to put it in my code."

This argument is in BaseSpider, which CrawlSpider inherits from. ([scrapy/spider.py](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spider.py#L54)) And it's set as True by default.

2."It can scrap only 10 or 15 records."

*Reason*: 
This is because the **start_urls** is not that good. 
In this problem, the spider starts crawling in http://www.khmer24.com/, and let's assume that it gets 10 urls to follow(which are satisfied the pattern). 
And then, the spider goes on crawling these 10 urls. But as these pages contain so little satisfied pattern, the spider gets a few urls to follow(even no urls), which results in stopping crawling.

*Possible solution*: 
The reason what I said above just restates *icecrime*'s opinion. And so does the solution.

- Suggest to use the 'All ads' page as **start_urls**. (You could also use the home page as **start_urls** and use the new **rules**.)
- New **rules**:

  ```
  rules = (
      # Extract all links and follow links from them 
      # (since no callback means follow=True by default)
      # (If "allow" is not given, it will match all links.)
      Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor()), 

      # Extract links matching the "ad/any-words/67-anynumber.html" pattern
      # and parse them with the spider's method parse_item (NOT FOLLOW THEM)
      Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'ad/.+/67-\d+\.html'), callback='parse_item'),
  )
  ```

Refer: 
[SgmlLinkExtractor](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html?highlight=allow#sgmllinkextractor), 
[CrawlSpider example](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example)

Comment: Hey there, when I run this code, it crawls every single pages in the site. However, I want it to crawl base on the rule that I have set only.

Comment: Do you want to crawl the whole site and get all urls that match the pattern?

Comment: the url that matches with the pattern http://www.khmer24.com/ad/any-words/67-anynumber-or-words.html

Comment: You just want to crawl all the urls which match the pattern, right?! But there is a problem, as I said above, if you didn't add another rule, you would only get a few urls.(Because urls you get in the first time contain little urls match the pattern, and the spider will stop as it hasn't urls to follow.)

Comment: I think what you want is to parse the page whose url matches the pattern, do you? In my solution, the spider will crawl the whole website in order to get every urls which matches, but not parses every url it gets. It just parses the urls which match the pattern. If you're still confused about this problem, email me.

Comment: +1 Your answer really helped me. I hadn't realised that the default behaviour for follow is different when a callback is specified. So each page I successfully parsed became a dead end instead of a route to other relevant sibling pages.