# Scrapy multiple Rules for SgmlLinkExtractor don't work

Tags: scrapy

I want to crawl entire site and extract the links conditionally.

As suggested in this link I tried with multiple Rules but it doesn't work. [Scrapy doesn't crawl all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147057/scrapy-doesnt-crawl-all-pages/16581301#16581301)

I tried with this code but it doesn't scrap any details.

```
class BusinesslistSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'businesslist'
    allowed_domains = ['www.businesslist.ae']
    start_urls = ['http://www.businesslist.ae/']

    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor()),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'company/(\d)+/'), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url)
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        i = BusinesslistItem()
        company = hxs.select('//div[@class="text companyname"]/strong/text()').extract()[0]
        address = hxs.select('//div[@class="text location"]/text()').extract()[0]
        location = hxs.select('//div[@class="text location"]/a/text()').extract()[0]
        i['url'] = response.url
        i['company'] = company
        i['address'] = address
        i['location'] = location
        return i
```

In my case it doesn't apply second rule, so it doesn't parse the detail pages.

Comment: Your first rule is empty. How do you know the second one works at all?

Comment: As the first rule is empty, it should crawl the entire site and it should extract the links which matches the second rule. According to Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147057/scrapy-doesnt-crawl-all-pages/16581301#16581301

Answer (score 1):

First rule `Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor())` matches every links, and scrapy just ignores the second one.

Try followings:

```
...
start_urls = ['http://www.businesslist.ae/sitemap.html']
...
# Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor()),
```

Comment: Can not we use multiple rules such as suggested in this link?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147057/scrapy-doesnt-crawl-all-pages/16581301#16581301
Because I want to call parse_item for only specific links.

Comment: Still don't understand what you want.

Comment: I Want to use multiple rules like this,
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor()),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r'company/(\d)+/'), callback='parse_item'),

So that first rule crawl the entire site and second rule scraped data from specific urls (i.e. detail page urls which contains "company/" in the url).

Comment: In your case, rule #1 will override rule #2, so #2 won't work. You should change rule #1 from "all links in the entire website" to "all links but doesn't matched rule #2" so rule #2 won't be ignored.

Comment: I am new to scrapy so can you give me the exact rules which should I try?